# JQuery Autocompete (devbridge) show suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm currently using [devbridge JQuery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete). I can't seem to find a way to manually trigger opening the options. Does anybody know a way to achieve this? It needs to trigger on focus, with an option already selected.

Comment: Try doing $('.your-input').autocomplete('onValueChange');

Comment: That didn't work :/ I've tried calling a lot of functions that way with no success...

Comment: One of this 2 solutions should work, not sure which one is your case: https://jsfiddle.net/dnxen2sk/

Comment: Sorry, I think I didnt explain correctly. I need it to open when focusing it, but when there's an option already selected. It works if it's empty, but not if there is an option.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, this? https://jsfiddle.net/dnxen2sk/1/